# PYthon, Deleting my DCIM File

Tags: android, python

Hey i am using qpython3 and want to delete my DCIM-File by using Python, but it still doesn´t work. I am using a Motorola Moto G 2. with Android 4.4:
Here´s the code what do I have to change?

```
import os
path = os.environ["sdcard"] + "/DCIM"
if os.path.exists(path) == True:
    print(path, "exists.")
    os.remove(path)
    print("File succesfully deleted.")
else:
    print(path,"File not existing.")
```

Keyerror: b "sdcard"

Thank you for yuór answers.

Comment: `print(os.environ)` would show you what values are available for you to use. Place it after `import os`

Comment: Name Error: Name "os" is not definied?

Comment: Oh sry my fault i forgot import os.... :D Thank you ;)